# What's the most effective way to Iterate, while manipulating a list or string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

My goal is to create a code breaker in python. So far I have jumbled up the letters and as a result have a list of individual characters.

```
#Result of inputting the string 'hello world'
['C', 'V', 'N', 'N', 'H', 'X', 'H', 'K', 'N', 'O']
```

**My aim is output this as a string with a space 'CVNNH XHKNO'**

Now I have several options but I'm unsure which one would the best:
Do I convert it to a string first before manipulating it or manipulate the list before converting to a string.

I have the following helpers available from the process so far (automatically)

```
length = [5,5] #list
total_chars = 10 #int
no_of_words = 2 #int
```

I have converted it to a string CVNNHXHKNO and thought about inserting the space after the 5th letter by calculating a start point[0], mid point[5] and end point[11].

```
start = 0
mid_point = total_chars - length[0]

print(mid_point)
first_word = message[start:mid_point]
print(first_word)

second_word = message[mid_point:total_chars]
print(second_word)

completed_word = first_word + ' ' + second_word
print(completed_word)
```

Unfortunately this is just manually and doesn't take into account if there a 5 or more words. I have attempted to iterate over the original list of individual characters in nested for loops using the list length but seem to confuse myself and overthink.

Comment: How does the number of words affect your goal of adding a space to a string?

Comment: Is `no_of_words` always the same as `len(length)`?

Comment: @ScottHunter I guess it's calculating the stages to put them in. Do I add them in the original list or the converted string?  Perhaps I am overthinking. I know what I want to do and once I figure it out will probably kick myself.

Comment: @quamrana Yes. I thought that may help my calculations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have this as inputs:

```
l = ['C', 'V', 'N', 'N', 'H', 'X', 'H', 'K', 'N', 'O']
length = [5,5] #list
total_chars = 10 #int
no_of_words = 2 #int
```

Then you can compute your output as follow:

```
words = []
pos = 0
for i in length:
  words.append("".join(l[pos:pos+i]))
  pos += i

result = " ".join(words)

print(words)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['CVNNH', 'XHKNO']
CVNNH XHKNO
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not fully understand your question, but probably what you want is something like

```
letters = ['C', 'V', 'N', 'N', 'H', 'X', 'H', 'K', 'N', 'O']
length = [5, 5]
words = []
offset = 0

for i in length:
    words.append(''.join(letters[offset:offset+i]))
    offset += i   

string_words = ' '.join(words)
print(string_words)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

WORD_SIZE = 5
NUM_WORDS = 2  # You could replace this with `len(lst) / WORD_SIZE`
result = ' '.join(
  ''.join(
    lst[i * WORD_SIZE: i * WORD_SIZE + 5]
  )
  for i in range(NUM_WORDS)
)

#  result = 'abcde fghij'
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use infinitely long lists of lengths as input, you could iterate over the `length` list and join the corresponding letters:

```
letters = ["A", "S", "I", "M", "P", "L", "E", "T", "E", "S", "T"]
length = [1, 6, 4]

starting_index = 0
for l in length:
    print("".join(letters[starting_index:starting_index+l]))
    starting_index += l
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just need your `length` list describing how many letters in each word:

```
message = ['C', 'V', 'N', 'N', 'H', 'X', 'H', 'K', 'N', 'O']

length = [5,5]

offset = 0
words = []
for size in length:
    words.append(''.join(message[offset:offset+size]))
    offset += size
completed_word = ' '.join(words)

print(completed_word)
```

Output:

```
CVNNH XHKNO
```

Comment: is not this just a copy of my answer, but different vars names

Comment: No. We answered completely independently and I have upvoted your answer as it seems to be the only other one which completely aligns with the requirements of the OP.

Comment: Sorry I am not accusing you, I am just saying new answers must add something new.

Comment: This is the problem with stack overflow when two people answer at the same time.